# How to create reusable component in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, components, reusability

Hi 
I want to make reusable component in/for Struts 2 framework. For example, a login form having validations, authentication on form submission, error display, Forgot password link etc. 
I want to create this form in such a way so that it can be placed anywhere within the site and in any site without any changes.

Please suggest what should I use or better if you can provide and reference for the example of such type of components.

Thanks
Krishan Babbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not, this is Model View Controller, source code can be reused, for example if you want to go to another framework, everything you will need to modify is View, because each framework has its specific tags, you could do everything with simple html tags, but this is already a framework problem